# How to keep console app on when listening to Firestore database

Tags: c#, .net, firebase

I have a simple function to listen to changes in firestore database, code shown below

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Google.Cloud.Firestore;

    namespace Firestore2

{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {

            Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", "credentials.json");
            FirestoreDb db = FirestoreDb.Create("example");
            Console.WriteLine("Success");
            
            // Create a random document ID. The document doesn't exist yet.
            DocumentReference doc = db.Collection("new").Document();
            FirestoreChangeListener listener = doc.Listen(snapshot =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Callback received document snapshot");
                Console.WriteLine($"Document exists? {snapshot.Exists}");
                if (snapshot.Exists)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Value of 'value' field: {snapshot.GetValue<int?>("value")}");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            });   
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works fine however the program closes after running listener once. Im still new to C# and I imagined the listener part will keep the program running but was wrong. How can I keep it running? Was hoping not to use loops

Comment: Why the aversion to loops? Consider writing something like "Press any key to quit" to the console and looping with a `do/while` loop using `!Console.KeyAvailable` as the condition

Comment: @Flydog57 I dont mind a lot if its a loop I thought there was a way to just keep listening  like in mobile apps

Comment: In a Windows app, you can leave a window up forever (even if it's hidden) and it can listen forever.  In console apps, control flows from the top to the bottom.  When you get to the bottom, it ends.   There are more complicated ways of doing this (involving other threads - in that case, you just make a blocking call on the main thread (Console.ReadKey, for example) and let the background thread do the looping work.  But, just a simple loop until a key becomes available should do the trick.  This is premised on `doc.Listen` being a blocking call (which I assume it is)

Comment: @Flydog57 Thanks well explained. Will try that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FirestoreChangeListener provides a property ListenerTask and a method StopAsync(). See https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/reference/Google.Cloud.Firestore/latest/Google.Cloud.Firestore.FirestoreChangeListener.

I would try the following approach:

```cs
private static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", "credentials.json");
    FirestoreDb db = FirestoreDb.Create("example");
    Console.WriteLine("Success");

    // Create a random document ID. The document doesn't exist yet.
    DocumentReference doc = db.Collection("new").Document();
    FirestoreChangeListener listener = doc.Listen(snapshot =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Callback received document snapshot");
        Console.WriteLine($"Document exists? {snapshot.Exists}");
        if (snapshot.Exists)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Value of 'value' field: {snapshot.GetValue<int?>("value")}");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    });

    // Handle CTRL+C (SIGINT)
    Console.CancelKeyPress += (sender, e) =>
    {
        // The current process should resume when the event handler concludes
        e.Cancel = true;
        listener.StopAsync();
    };
    await listener.ListenerTask;
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Works perfect, Thanks. Thought I commented before but now realised its not there